# How to make content fit the full screen (Mapbox)

Tags: css, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using a map api (Mapbox). I'm trying to make the map fit the full screen, but nothing I try seems to work.

I have a wrapper and container for the map. I've tried to different solutions, but I'm still having problems.

**Option 1**: *problem*: the map doesn't fit the viewport, instead a scroll bar is added forcing the user to scroll down to view the entire map

[jsfiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/khuspfmr/)

**Option 2**: *problem*: the map fills the entire viewport, but the bottom portion of the map is cut off (notice the mapbox logo is missing at the bottom)

[jsfiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/8oLjd51a/)

How can I get the map to fit the view port without being cutoff or adding a scroll bar?

**Full code for reference:**

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA';

class Application extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map', // container id
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9', // stylesheet location
            center: [13.392, 52.523], // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });
        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
    }

    render() {
        return (
<div>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>Hi</p>    
                    <div className="map-wrapper">
                        <div ref={this.mapContainer} id="map"/>
                    </div>
              </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.map-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
   height: 100% !important.
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: It is probably 100% of none it's none ^^ add some width or height in pixel. Or 100vh and 100vw respectively for height and width. Use overflow to avoid scrolling and zindex for stack position.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the wrapper. Simply set your height and width to 100vh and 100vw respectively.

```
#map {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).